# Not able to run full screen you tube video in DJ Native Browser

Tags: java, windows, swing, swt, djnativeswing

I want to run full screen you tube video in Swing Native browse, But i
am not able to run. i am not getting any exception. in my native
browser screen only black color cross button is display on the top
left corner of my jFarme. in my 32 bit windows machine its working
file. but when i try it on 64 bit windows machine its not working.
Please help me if you know something about my problem

**Jar's i used :**

`DJNativeSwing.jar`, `DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar`, `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64-4.3.jar`

**Tryed URL's**

https://www.youtube.com/v/hk5IMmEDWH4

https://www.youtube.com/v/b-cr0ewwatk?fs=1

**Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    NativeInterface.open();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("YouTube Viewer");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.getContentPane().add(getBrowserPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setSize(1024, 800);
            frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    NativeInterface.runEventPump();
    // don't forget to properly close native components
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NativeInterface.close();
        }
    }));
}

public static JPanel getBrowserPanel() {
    JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
    webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
    webBrowser.navigate(URL);
    return webBrowserPanel;
}
```